# add new object not opened in a modal dialog

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, modal-dialog

After installing Cumulative updates (August 2012 - only SharePoint server) now when you click "add new object" link to add new object to a lists on all pages (except document libraries) the NewForm does not open in a modal dialog. I have checked advance setting of all lists and Launch forms in a dialog?  is ON.

Comment: Do you get a javascript error on the page? (because the modal dialog is launched with javascript...)

Comment: Yeah, fire up Chrome and the js debugger and see if you get any errors

Comment: Ruben Herman; No, no javascript error

Comment: Does anybody has an answer for it? I am facing same problem. info : no javascript error and setting is ON